# sql query to select a random value (weighted)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with three fields: ID,Value,Count

ID and Value make up the PK.

Given an ID I want to select a value weighted by Count and then decrement the count by one.

So If I have

```
1  A  2
1  B  3
```

I should have a 2/5 chance of getting an A and a 3/5 chance of getting a B.
If A is selected the table should look like this after

```
1  A  1
1  B  3
```

Next time A will have a 1/4 chance of being selected and B will have a 3/4

Ideas?

Thanks!

Update:

The Weight is like the number of chips of that value that would be placed in a bag. And then one randomly chosen.

Comment: what happens when weight becomes '0'

Comment: it is no longer included in the calculation

Comment: and can you have two values with the same weight? what happens then, one gets picked randomly?

Comment: also, how many records will you have in this table?

Comment: What version of SQL Server? And how many records per `id` (on average) and is there a maximum weight value?

Comment: 26 records per id. If there were 3 A's, 3 B's and 2 C's then it would be a 3/8 chance of an A 3/8 of a B and a 2/8 chance of a C

Comment: What is the largest possible number in the `Count` column? My answer uses a numbers table that can cope with up to 2047 currently.

Comment: something like 10. I feel like the answers are too complicated. I would think there would be a way generate a select statement that returned the number of rows equals to the sum of the weights. Then order by NEWID and select the top one...

Comment: @kralco626 I was thinking about that, too, but I could not come up with a way to make 3 rows out of one, just because there is a "3" in some column of that row.

Comment: @kralco626 - That is essentially what my answer does but you also have the requirement to `update` the row!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #Vals
(
ID INT,
Value CHAR(1),
[Count] INT,
PRIMARY KEY(ID,Value)
)

INSERT INTO #Vals
SELECT 1,'A',2 UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'B',3

;WITH Nums AS
(
SELECT number 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE number>0 AND type='P'
), Row AS
(
SELECT TOP 1 v.*
FROM #Vals v
JOIN Nums n ON n.number <= v.[Count]
WHERE v.ID=1
ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NEWID())
)
UPDATE Row 
SET [Count] = [Count] -1
OUTPUT inserted.*


DROP TABLE #Vals
```

Comment: You confused me :) I don't really understand what the code is doing

Comment: @kralco626 - If the weight is 10 (for example) it joins onto the numbers table to expand that out to 10 rows, allocates a random weight to each row, sorts the results using a `TOP N` sort (it doesn't have to actualy sort the result set in its entirety it is only interested in the `TOP 1` weighted row) then updates that selected row to decrement the counter and uses the `OUTPUT` clause to return the result to the client. I wasn't sure that doing `weight*random number` was good maths or not. If it turns out it is then that will be easy enough to implement.

Comment: Good idea... by joining with a table of all natural numbers we can make multiple rows out of one row. Then we can just randomly pick a row.

Comment: OH! now I get it, thanks AndreKR, didn't get that he was selecting a table of all natural numbers! +1

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL (maybe someone could translate it into an MSSQL UPDATE statement?) this would give you the line that needs to be decremented:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE ID = 1
AND (
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Count), 0)
  FROM t i
  WHERE ID = 1
  AND i.Value < t.Value
) <= (
  SELECT FLOOR(SUM(Count) * RAND())
  FROM t
)
ORDER BY Value DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Because it's O(n²), it will be slow for large sets of data, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (provided you don't have too many records in this table). I made a structure like so:

```
id          value                                              weight
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -----------
1           A                                                  2
1           B                                                  3
```

And then ran the below code. Keep in mind that after a certain time, all your weight will become zero, and at that point you will have no returned value. Also, I am assuming that if there is no weight match based on the random return, then return the most weight value. If that is not what you want, just take out the last null check

```
declare @weight_sum int
declare @rand_weight_value int
declare @selected_value varchar(10)
declare @id int
declare @weight int

select @weight_sum = SUM(weight) from table1 where id = 1
select @rand_weight_value = ROUND(((@weight_sum - 1) * RAND() + 1), 0) 

print @rand_weight_value

declare getEm cursor local  for select ID, [value], [weight] from table1 where id = 1 and [weight] > 0 order by [weight]

open getEm
        while (1=1)
        begin
                 fetch next from getEm into @id, @selected_value, @weight

                 if (@@fetch_status  0)
                    begin
                        DEALLOCATE getEm
                        break
                    end


                if(@weight >= @rand_weight_value)
                begin
                        update table1 set [weight] = [weight] - 1 where ID = @id and [value] = @selected_value

                        DEALLOCATE getEm
                        break
                end

        end

-- if no match on the weight value
if(@selected_value is null)
begin
    select @id = id, @selected_value = [value] from table1 where [weight] > 0 and id = 1 order by weight desc
         update table1 set weight = weight - 1 where id = @id
end
select @selected_value
```

Comment: Shouldn't you sum up all the @weights you already fetched and compare that sum against @rand_wight_value?

Comment: +1 for being (hopefully) valid MSSQL code and solving the performance issues by walking the data only once

Comment: The Weight is like the number of chips of that value that would be placed in a bag. And then one randomly chosen.

Comment: Yes, and the @weight_sum is the number of chips. So he chooses a @rand_weight_value between 0 and the number of chips and then compares it to the @weight of a single value.

Comment: @AndreKR - yes, I am adding them up in the beginning to generate the random value, that will then be compared against each of the weights.... ideally I would like to even avoid one walk across the whole table.... I wish there was some way I could test for ranges...

Comment: Imagine the Count values in the DB are 3,2,3,5,6. Then the @weight_sum is 19 and @rand_weight_value is a value between 1 and 19. Then for @rand_weight_values between 6 and 19 no row will be updated and for smaller @rand_weight_values the first row with a @weight greater than that will be updated. I think that's not what you meant.

Comment: @andreKr - ahh, yes - it just needs another update after the last null check, 'if' the rand value is higher than 6

Comment: That changes nothing. Then (in the given example) for a @rand_weight_value between 6 and 19 the row with the largest Count (5) is updated. That means, the effective weight of that row is not 5 but 19-6=13.

Comment: @andrekr  - that is correct, being that there is no rows with weight above 6, then the highest one wins.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is that the chance it wins is almost 70% (it wins in 13 of 19 times) and not 26% (5 of 19) as it is expected.